# Power BI - Store each latest date (refresh history) to a table OR other hack in power bi desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, power-automate, m

I am about to lose my head to solve the following issue. It would be easy for members who usually use Power Query, but not for me, as i have done a little work with it (I have always used DAX).

I'm facing an issue related to data where i only have the first two columns ["Requirements", "Values"] of the following dataset as an example, and my target is to add a refresh date or some other hack that whenever my data got a refresh, a date is added here which could connect to Calendar table. Later, i will create a line chart that shows the percentage of "Requirements" linked to the "Values". Each time the report gets updated, the line chart shows a percentage trend with a new refresh date added to the table.

[image]

And this is the end goal I want to achieve.
[image]

Can you please guide me if there is any hack/way around to achieve it in Power BI?

Comment: @Promethee, thank you for your comment. Can you please explain more in detail how it works. I created a shared drive [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FZKj8xyGzDZSgcGJgUA-TF6Xqqzj5vWd] with dummy Excel and PBI file. I'm only using excel in a dummy file, but in production, data is coming from Jira automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming strictly one extract is performed on ***every*** calendar day from StartDate (which would be a Power Query parameter of type date containing the adequate date), you could create a column "Refresh Date" like this (and then type it in an additional step):

```
= Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(PreviousStep) & {List.Combine(List.Transform({0..Table.RowCount(PreviousStep)/2 - 1}, each {Date.AddDays(StartDate, _), Date.AddDays(StartDate, _)}))}, Table.ColumnNames(PreviousStep) & {"Refresh Date"})
```

If it is only extracted on some kind of working days, then you should adjust this column (probably as a simple day counter) and correlate it to some working days counter column in your calendar.

Here are a few explanations (for one extraction per calendar day with rows ordered chronologically):

- Generate a list with all extraction days (from 0 to Nb of days - 1) with "{0..Table.RowCount(PreviousStep)/2 - 1}".
- Then Duplicate each nb in this list as you have two lines for the same day.

  - Actually "List.Transform(...)" generates a list of lists {{0, 0}, {1, 1},...} and then add these numbers to StartDate (typ. to 2024-03-01).
  - In the end, we get {{2024-03-01, 2024-03-01}, {2024-03-02, 2024-03-02},...}.
- List.Combine gives one single list thanks to List.Combine: {2024-03-01, 2024-03-01, 2024-03-02, 2024-03-02,...}.
- Then we can add a list to the table as a new column through Table.FromColumns but this works only if we first convert the table as a list through Table.ToColumns.

Comment: don't think it's possible as PBI does not store data so at each refresh the previous dates will be removed. Even using a baseline date won't allow you to identify the new lines so any date added would need to have some constant like start date + xx each xx lines. Maybe you could look into "incremental refresh".

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a more academic method by adding an index column starting at 0 then adding a column created like this: "= Table.AddColumn(#"Added index", "Refresh date", each Date.AddDays(StartDate, Number.RoundDown([Index] / 2)), type number)".

Comment: Indeed (adding a linear value) but this also assumes the order of the new values will always be added at the bottom of the table which is not guaranteed from my understanding.

Comment: @Promethee, thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I cannot follow the steps mentioned in your comments. Is there any way you can use some dummy data and provide me with a PBI report as an example? 
I'm still confused if there is a way for the stored data to come from Jira issues (in a real scenario), which is later summarized in PBI and added a refresh date. Then, how does the previous refresh date stay the same as the # of summarized issues, and how is the new refresh date added to the latest # of summarized issues?

Comment: @Promethee, here are the  [Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FZKj8xyGzDZSgcGJgUA-TF6Xqqzj5vWd?usp=drive_link) dummy files (Power BI & Excel).

Comment: It is still unclear to me whether my assumptions are correct.
Slightly adapting my step to your PBI Query (with hard-coded start date):
  `= Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") & {List.Combine(List.Transform({0..Table.RowCount(#"Changed Type")/2 - 1}, each {Date.AddDays(#date(2023, 3, 1), _), Date.AddDays(#date(2023, 3, 1), _)}))}, Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type") & {"Refresh Date"})`

Comment: Hi @Promethee, i don't think your approach is suitable for this question. I tried to apply, and the result is not fulfilling the requirements. 
I aim to add a refresh date whenever data gets refreshed and keep historical data based on the refresh date.

Comment: As ceci said, this is not possible with Power BI. Depending on the exact details, this could be achieved with an Excel table generated by Power Query and used in input again by Power Query

Comment: @Promethee, thank you for your response. Do you have any idea how to achieve it by collecting number of issues from Jira and saving it automatically in Excel via Power Query?

Comment: `let
    JiraSource = Input,
    #"Source for previous output" = Output_Callback,
    #"Combine Previous Outputs + New Inputs" = Table.Combine({#"Source for previous output", Table.RemoveFirstN(JiraSource, Table.RowCount(#"Source for previous output"))}),
    #"Set today as refresh date for new inputs" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Combine Previous Outputs + New Inputs",null, Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) ,Replacer.ReplaceValue, {"Date Refresh"})
in
    #"Set today as refresh date for new inputs"`
Where source1 is your Jira 2-col. input and source2 is the callback of PQ output.

Comment: Then automate this with whatever you have. Maybe Power Automate? or if nothing better, some Workbook_open VBA macro launching the refresh of the query and saving the file. Note that you should deactivate background execution (Data => Existing connections - right-click on the output query => uncheck "Enable background refresh") for the refresh to be executed in synchronous mode with VBA (the file could be opened with Windows task scheduler if no better solution is available).